# Cocos2d: troubles scheduling call a method multiple times at specific time intervals

Tags: methods, time, cocos2d-iphone, scheduled-tasks, call

I ran the following code expecting to schedule three subsequent calls, at different time intervals (e.g. after 1 sec, after 2.6sec etc..) on the method "**displayWarningMessage**" but didn't work (it displayed the massage only the first time).

I don't find a method signature in the scheduler that would do the job of displaying it multiple times and with a specific delay. Anyone has some suggestion?

```
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(displayWarningMessage)  delay:0.7f];
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(displayWarningMessage)  delay:1.7f];
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(displayWarningMessage)  delay:3.7f];
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is, when you call first schedule it is scheduled successfully. But the next immediate call is throwing warning something

```
CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: X.2 to X.2
```

you can see this in the log.

What you can do is when the selector is called, at the end of the method you can schedule it again for the next time, until you are done. You may take a counter to keep track of how many times it has been called, put all of your intervals in an array and then schedule next selector for the interval at the specific index identified by counter. like this:

```
NSArray *intervals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.7],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.7], nil];

int counter = 0;

//schedule it for the first time with object at index counter/index 0
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(displayWarningMessage)  delay:[(NSNumber *)[intervals objectAtIndex:counter]] floatValue];
```

now in your selector, do something like this:

```
-(void)displayWarningMessage
{
    //do all your stuff here

    //increment counter
    counter ++;

    if(counter < [intervals count])
    {
        //schedule it for the next time with object at index counter/index 
        [self scheduleOnce:@selector(displayWarningMessage)  delay:[(NSNumber *)[intervals objectAtIndex:counter]] floatValue];
    }
}
```

`intervals` and `counter` should be class ivars of-course.

Comment: thank u very much, is a nice idea but I tried and did not work. As a proof, in the code u suggested I substituted the call to scheduleOnce instead all the controls below the comment "Do all your stuff here" and it still wouldn't call it. I am not sure if it is me doing something wrong or what. I am using Cocos2d v2.0 and ARC enabled. For now +1 vote for ur brillant idea but I keep the answer as unaccepted as did not solve completely the issue (but will accept if nothing else comes up).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)displayWarningMessage {
    //Stuff
}

- (void)callStuff {
    CCCallFunc *call = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayWarningMessage)];
    CCDelayTime *delay1 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.7f];
    CCDelayTime *delay2 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.7f];
    CCDelayTime *delay3 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3.7f];
    CCSequence *actionToRun = [CCSequence actions:delay1, call, delay2, call, delay3, call, nil];
    [self runAction:actionToRun];
}
```

That should work for what you're trying to do, at least that's how I'd imagine doing it. I'm fairly sure you can call that CCCallFunc multiple times in one CCSequence without having to create it three individual times. You could also make those delays variable based if need be, of course. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

Method is created.

```
[self schedule: @selector(displayWarningMessage:) interval:3.2f];

-(void) displayWarningMessage:(ccTime) delta
{

    CCLOG(@"alert........!!!!!!");

}
```

Use the Calling method in not warning message detected.

Comment: Please use 4 spaces in front of the code to format it as code.